# Issue with passing Json string as parameter from angularjs to webservice

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I am trying to pass json string from angularjs to my websrvice  and used below code.Can someone please let me where i went wrong with the below code?

Controller method:

```
[httpget]
public string BulkData(JObject jObjectData)
{
   var x = jObjectData;
   return (jObjectData != null ) ? “SUCCESS”: “FAIL”;
}
```

Javasctiprt method :

```
function Get(url, data) { 
    var getReq = {
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8" }
    };
   return $http(getReq).then(function (response) {

        $log.debug('**response from EXECUTE:', response);

        return response;

    }, function (error) {

        $log.error('**error from EXECUTE', error);

        return error;

    });
      }
```

Comment: You need [HttpPost] method, and make post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `[HttpPost]` method, and make post request

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public string BulkData(JObject jObjectData)
{
   var x = jObjectData;
   return (jObjectData != null ) ? “SUCCESS”: “FAIL”;
}
```

Javasctiprt method :

```
function Get(url, data) { 
    var getReq = {
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8" }
    };
   return $http(getReq).then(function (response) {

        $log.debug('**response from EXECUTE:', response);

        return response;

    }, function (error) {

        $log.error('**error from EXECUTE', error);

        return error;

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response. Does it always to be POST ?

Comment: yes, if you want to submit data in body than you need POST method, in your case you need post method

Comment: When I changed to POST , BulkData method is not called.

Comment: @user3403437 what error are you seeing in network tab/ console tab

Comment: In network tab, I can see 500 error. this call is invoking different method than BulkData that's why I see 500 error.not sure why It is calling the different method?

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` is not required for POST . `invoking different method` it should not , unless you are messing with something at controller end .